# Почему бекграунд разного цвета на разных API?

Tags: java, android, android-style

Я вот заметил, что когда я загружаю `app` с `Activity` на котором у меня 1 кнопка на `Galaxy S5 API 21` то фон `Activity` белого цвета, когда я ту же app загружаю на `HTC Desire 500 API 19` то фон уже черный..

И получается, что возникает проблема с дизайном...

Как сделать так, чтоб фон всегда был того цвета который нужен? 
Я думал, это в стилях должно быть, но почему тогда для одного девайса подбирается один цвет для другого другой...

Единственное решение которое пришло в голову это дописывать на каждом `Activity`

```
android:background=""
```

Кто знает это единственное решение или можно все же где то в настройках указать??

Вот так добавил атрибут стилей

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <windowBackground>#ffffff</windowBackground>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/stardavida</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужен атрибут стилей

```
windowBackground
```

т.е. в `styles.xml` в стиле приложения пишем:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос атрибут стилей, но у меня не работает... Как его правльно добавить?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, попробуйте так: `<item name="android:windowBackground">#ffffff</item>`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, пожалуйста) Ответ дополнил.